# Projection of a point on a line

Tags: analytic-geometry

> Find the projection of the point $(-6,4)$ onto the line $4x-5y+3=0$

I can find the distance between the point and the line, but I do not think it can help

Comment: I'm assuming you want to project it to the line orthogonally?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're talking about the orthogonal projection. So let's find the equation of the perpendicular to the given line through the given point. The equation of a perpendicular is of the form

$$5x+4y+c=0$$

It passes through $(-6,4)$ so $c=30-16=14$. The projection (orthogonal) is the intersection of the two lines

$$\begin{cases}4x-5y+3=0\\5x+4y+14=0\end{cases}$$

The intersection point is $(-2,-1)$

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this problem is to first find the line that goes through $(-6,4)$ and is perpendicular to $4x-5y+3=0$. Since the slope of the given line is $m_0=\frac{4}{5}$, the slope of a line perpendicular to $4x-5y+3=0$ will be $m_1=-\frac{5}{4}$. Now you have a point $(-6,4)$ and a slope $m_1=-\frac{5}{4}$, so it is simple to find the line defined by that point and slope.

The projection of $(-6,4)$ to $4x-5y+3=0$ will then be the intersection of the given line and the perpendicular line found.